# Shortcut key to create line of code

Tags: vba, ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Microsoft Access 2010 and I was just curios to know if I can set up my own short cut keys to fill lines of code out for me.

For example if I did:
Hold Ctrl and pressed 1 it would print out the line of code:
Debug.Print "This is creating a line of code from a shortcut key"

Is this possible to do in VBA?

Comment: Look into [MZ Tools for VBA](http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx).  You can set up custom code snippets which can be assigned to keyboard shortcuts. It offers many other useful features, too ... it's worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [MZ-tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) in my VBA IDE. It allows this kind of functionality (along with a lot of other cool things)

When you get it installed you will want to create a Code Template. Go to

`Tools > MZ-Tools > Options > Code Templates`

`Add...` a new template like so:
[image: MA-tools code template]

`OK > OK`

No in your IDE press Ctrl+1 and out pops

`Debug.Print "This is creating a line of code from a shortcut key"`

You can use variables in this template too if you want to get fancy.